# Product import with store manager Magento

Tags: magento, import

![enter image description here][1]I need help with product import. I am importing the products using Magento store manager provided by mag-manager. If anybody have experience with it, can you tell me what is the issue with bundle options pricing.
Rest of all like, related prodcuts, products prices, images and categories, everything works smooth and import perfectly, but it shows the bundle options price 0 for all the options. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a programming section of StackExchange and administration/implementation questions about the web application Magento are best served if asked over in magento.stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

Magento logics as well as Store Manager's is the following - the price of bundle product is dynamic, so it means that is it accumulative and calculated from associated simple products. Thus, you need to import the price of associated simple products from your file.